# Left Join or Group By for Finding Maximum Salary in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I am trying to understand why it is a popular belief that avoiding a group by is always beneficial. My problem statement is : From an employee table where department_id is a foreign key, find out those departments where an employees maximum salary is 40000

## 1 the group by approach :

```
 select d.department_name , e.max_salary 
   from department d
   join ( select department_id, max(salary) as max_salary
   from emp 
   group by 1
   having max_salary = 40000 ) e
   on (d.department_id = e.department_id)
```

## 2  Now the left join approach :

```
 select d.department_name, inner_q.salary
 from    department d
 join
 (select e.department_id , e.salary
  from  emp  e
  left join emp  e_inner
  on (e.department_id = e_inner.department_id and e.salary < e_inner.salary)
  where e_inner.department_id is null and e.salary = 40000 ) inner_q
  on (d.department_id = inner_q.department_id)
```

Unfortunately explain plan does not make much sense to me. Any help in explaining which one should perform better and why would be much appreciated.

Comment: "it is a popular belief that avoiding a group by is always beneficial" - can you provide a reference for this conjecture.

Comment: Try any BI product company trying to sell snake oil and they will start the pitch how time/resource consuming aggregates are...

Comment: @Strawberry  Thanks. I am new to the jargon so apologies for ignorance. So which one is 'uncorelated' sub query ? The group by option or the left join one ?

Comment: Several Employees belong to one particular department (let's say HR has 200 employees, IT has 500 employees and so on...)

Comment: So, it asks for if an organization has , say 10 departments, find that one (or more department) where highest salary given to an employee is 40000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working too hard.

```
SELECT  department_name, MAX(salary) AS max_salary
    FROM  emp
    GROUP BY  department_name
    HAVING  max_salary >= 40000
```

That will be faster than any version with subqueries.

This will make it run faster:  `INDEX(department_name, salary)`

(Perhaps you want `>= 40000`, not `= 40000`?)

This version will make a single pass over the entire table (or `INDEX`, if you add that "covering" index), gathering the max salary for each department.  Then it will throw away results that fail the `HAVING` clause; delivering the rest.

I would have not qualms about running this `GROUP BY` on a table of 10K rows.  A million-row table would take a noticeable, but small, amount of time.